# alphabatically retreving data in php

Tags: php

hi im very new to php and i did some small project(medicare system)
i created a database called "chapa",
and created a table called "drug".

there is a field called "des" in that table "des"=description
 my table fields are =codeno!qty!size!des!rate
all i want is that "des" to be shown in alphabatically with other fields

that means the data which i enterd to "des" should be retrive with alphabatically

i'm asking the way that i can retreive these data in "des"
thanks

Comment: Database? What database?

Comment: `SELECT ... ORDER BY des`? Have you learned some basics of SQL, or whatever database you're using?

Comment: You need to learn SQL for your Database.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're after an sql statement that will order the results by 'des'

```
SELECT * FROM drug ORDER BY des ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from chapa.drug order by des asc
```

where `asc` shows the ascending order or sorting (as opposed to `desc`)

Comment: he asked for "des ... with other fields", so needs to be SELECT * or field list, rather than just des.